# Complicated integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Please provide any idea how can I solve the following integral? does it have a solution in general? Thanks. 
$$
\int\ (ax+b)^{\alpha}x^{\beta}dx\,.
$$
$$
0<\alpha<1, \beta>1 , 
$$

And beta is a Real value number.

Comment: Integration by parts $w$ times will give you a sum of terms

Comment: Are $z,w$ integers? Positive integers?  If so, would a recursive relation be acceptable as a "general" solution?

Comment: No, they're Real values. 0<z<1 and w>1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a binomial–Chebyshev integral.
$$ \int x^p \left( c_1 x^q + c_0 \right) ^r dx $$
where *p*, *q*, *r* are rational. If *r* is a nonnegative integer, just expand it and have fun! Otherwise, set *y* = *x*<sup>*q*</sup> and then *dy* = *qx*<sup>*q*-1</sup>*dx*, leading to
$$ \frac 1 q \int y^ {\frac {p+1} {q} - 1} \left( c_1 y + c_0 \right) ^r dy. $$

As a result, we only have to consider
$$ \int x^{r_1} \left( c_1 x + c_0 \right) ^{r_2} dx $$
where *r*<sub>1</sub> and *r*<sub>2</sub> are rational. Let *n*<sub>1</sub> be the denominator of *r*<sub>1</sub>, *n*<sub>2</sub> the one of *r*<sub>2</sub>.

- When *r*<sub>1</sub> is a positive integer, set *z* = *c*<sub>1</sub>*x* + *c*<sub>0</sub>.
- When *r*<sub>1</sub> is a negative integer, set *z* = (*c*<sub>1</sub>*x* + *c*<sub>0</sub>)<sup>1/*n*<sub>2</sub></sup>.
- When *r*<sub>2</sub> is a negative integer, set *z* = *x*<sup>1/*n*<sub>1</sub></sup>.
- When *r*<sub>1</sub> + *r*<sub>2</sub> is an integer, set $z = \dfrac {\left( c_1 x + c_0 \right) ^{1/n_1}} {x^{1/n_1}}$.
- Otherwise, the integral is inexpressible in finite terms, according to [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29).

For example, consider
$$ \int \sqrt x \left( x+1 \right) ^{5/2} dx. $$
Set $ z = \dfrac {\sqrt{x+1}} {\sqrt x} $, so $ dx = - \dfrac {2z\,dz} {\left( z^2 - 1 \right) ^2} $. This simplifies the integrand into a rational function.
$$ \int \sqrt x \left( x+1 \right) ^{5/2} dx = \int - \frac {2z^6} {\left( z^2 - 1 \right) ^5} dz. $$

Comment: would you please explain a bit the last bullet "the integral is inexpressible in finite terms, according to Liouville's theorem". i couldn't get it. Thanks.

Comment: If we accept an antiderivative in infinite terms, then we accept series for an answer.  However, even if each term is an elementary function, the sum does not have to be elementary.

**Symbolic integration** now is in Leibniz's way, i.e. we only accept answers in finite terms, even if there is complicated functions like arctan.  Integration in series is the Newton's way. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may write it in general as a $_2F_1$ hypergeometric series for $r:=\frac ab$ and using :

\begin{align}
\int\ (1+r\,x)^{\alpha}\ x^{\beta-1}dx&=\int x^{\beta-1}\left(1+(-\alpha)\frac{(-rx)}{1!}+(-\alpha)(1-\alpha)\frac{(-rx)^2}{2!}+\cdots\right)dx\\
&=\frac{x^\beta}{\beta}\left(1+\frac{(-\alpha)(\beta)}{(\beta+1)}\frac{(-rx)}{1!}+\frac{(-\alpha)(1-\alpha)(\beta)(\beta+1)}{(\beta+1)(\beta+2)}\frac{(-rx)^2}{2!}+\cdots\right)\\
&=\frac{x^\beta}{\beta}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-\alpha)_j(\beta)_j}{(\beta+1)_j}\frac{(-rx)^j}{j!}\\
&=\frac{x^\beta}{\beta}\;
_{2}F_{1}\left.\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-\alpha&&\beta\\
&\beta+1\\
\end{array}\right|\ -r\,x\right)
\end{align}

Not sure that this expression will help much except in [specific cases](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/) (many formulas are known)...

Comment: Thanks. sounds nice, however not quite what I am looking for (If I understood it well!). thanks again.

Comment: @fzave: I fear that there is no 'simple' general formula. Did you have a specific application in mind (or precise bounds for your integral) ?

Comment: I think you are right. Actually that's part of an Economic equilibrium model. I just wanted to try to solve the integral to have a closed form solution. seems I have to quit! However still I should definitely go and learn about the 2F1 hypergeometric. Thanks.